# gcc 6.2.0 is attempting to create shared object when it shouldn't?

Tags: gcc, assembly, dynamic, static, gcc6

With non relocatable assembler code linking was never a problem up until gcc 6.2.0. I don't know the exact version that stared this, but with gcc 5.4.0 (and below) this worked:

```
$ gcc -o httpget ../obj/httpget.o ../../../lib/libribs2_ssl.a -lssl -lcrypto
```

However, with gcc 6.2.0:

```
$ gcc -o httpget ../obj/httpget.o ../../../lib/libribs2_ssl.a -lssl -lcrypto
/usr/bin/ld: ../../../lib/libribs2_ssl.a(context_asm.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `current_ctx' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Trying to force static linking creates another problem:

```
$ gcc -static -o httpget ../obj/httpget.o ../../../lib/libribs2_ssl.a -lssl -lcrypto -ldl
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_globallookup':
(.text+0x11): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
../obj/httpget.o: In function `main':
/home/nir/ribs2/examples/httpget/src/httpget.c:194: warning: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```

And the program segfaults when using gethostbyname() (but works otherwise)

Also trying to mix static and dynamic doesn't work.

```
$ gcc -o httpget -Wl,-Bstatic ../obj/httpget.o ../../../lib/libribs2_ssl.a -Wl,-Bdynamic -lssl -lcrypto
/usr/bin/ld: ../../../lib/libribs2_ssl.a(context_asm.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `current_ctx' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any ideas? Link to the project: https://github.com/niryeffet/ribs2

Comment: I am guessing it might want to create a PIE by default? Although according to gcc.godbolt.org, that's not the case. Anyway, you might want to try adding `-fno-PIE`, and also maybe compile a different test program that works and see if the output is PIE or not.

Comment: Thank you, -no-pie when linking did it.

Comment: Where does this problem come from ? I had this problem by upgrading my system...

Comment: @Saroupille, please see update below. I'm guessing that other distros are doing the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from @Jester: adding -no-pie (not -fno-PIE) to LDFLAGS solved the problem.

```
gcc -no-pie -o httpget ../obj/httpget.o ../../../lib/libribs2_ssl.a -lssl -lcrypto
```

The change also works on gcc 5.4. It seems as the default has changed.

**UPDATE:**

This explains it. From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/PIE

> In Ubuntu 16.10, as an additional compiler hardening measure, we've
>   enabled PIE and immediate binding by default on amd64 and ppc64le.
>   This greatly increases the effectiveness of ASLR on those platforms.