# "Nonrepresentable section on output" when compiling GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, gnu-make, position-independent-code

I'm trying to compile the GCC from source with module-TS support and I cloned to the devel branch (as stated [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-modules)) :

```
git clone --branch devel/c++-modules git://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git SRCDIR
```

Here's my configuration options :

```
./configure --disable-shared --disable-bootstrap --disable-libstdcxx-pch 
--enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-libgomp --enable-lto --enable-threads=posix --enable-tls    
--with-gmp=/tmp/gcc --with-mpfr=/tmp/gcc --with-mpc=/tmp/gcc --with-libelf=/tmp/gcc --with-fpmath=sse
```

And `make` gave me the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/../lib64/libstdc++.a(compatibility.o): relocation R_X86_64_32
against symbol `_ZTIN10__cxxabiv115__forced_unwindE' can not be used when making a shared
object; recompile with -fPIC

/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And similar errors for `sso_string.o` , `istream-inst.o` , etc.
What does that mean?
How can I recompile that with `-fPIC`?

Do I need to patch the Makefiles?
Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: You may try with `--enable-cxx-flags='-fPIC'` but I'm not sure this is the solution

Comment: Tried it.Exact same errors.

Comment: This may sound as silly, but have you done a `make clean`?

Comment: @MatteoRagni Yes.

Comment: With flag `--with-pic=yes`?

Comment: I did a "make distclean" and repeated the process from beginning with those options.But nothing.It still says recompile with -fPIC.

Comment: Because I suspect the issue is on the instaled library `libstdc++.a`, not on something you are currently compiling. I'm looking at this issue, check it out to see if there is some information useful for you https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54482

Comment: Not sure if your problem has been solved, but this seems quite similar to the problems mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246054/gcc-6-2-0-is-attempting-to-create-shared-object-when-it-shouldnt and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470945/relocation-r-x86-64-32s-against-data-can-not-be-used-when-making-a-shared-obj